# How to optimise passenger when it is showing "Website is under heavy load" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

On our Ruby on Rails website, I am seeing "Website is under heavy load" error and when I run

passenger-status, I see

[image]

I am also seeing

```
Max pool size : 6
App groups    : 1
Processes     : 6
Requests in top-level queue : 0
```

I am trying to figure out which is the best way to optimise passenger.

I tried to increase the Queue size from 100 to 200 in apache.conf file but it is not working and it still shows 100 as max.

```
# I tried both one by one
PassengerMaxRequestQueueSize 200
passenger_max_request_queue_size 200
```

What can I do to improve passenger performance so the site stops doing down under heavy load?

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise `passenger_max_pool_size N` for nginx or `PassengerMaxPoolSize N` for apache. You don't need to increase the queue size. This will allow passenger to spawn more processes and will be able to handle more requests. If you have enough memory and cpu you can raise it to 20 or even 30. More info https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/optimization/

Comment: Hi Chris, which is the right place to put this this variable? in apache.conf or in .htaccess file in root folder? I am on Ubuntu running Ruby on Rails app

I am checking https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/optimization/ but it doesn't show where to put the variable

Comment: You need to set in your apache.conf